# ngb-carousel not loading properly on page refresh in an angular application

Tags: angular, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ngb-carousel in my angular application for a simple website, everything is working fine but whenever i refresh, carousel's image doesn't load quickly whereas  indicators and arrows gets loaded.

[image: screen shot of the defect]

I'm wondering is there any solution for this ?. I tried putting a min-height so that atleast it looks aesthetic even if the image is not loaded. I would be very grateful for any suggestions or solutions. My code related to the carousel goes like this.

Parent component:

```
<div style="min-height: 500px;">
  <banner-slider></banner-slider>
</div>
```

Banner Slider Component:

```
<ngb-carousel 
  [showNavigationArrows]="true" 
  [showNavigationIndicators]="true"
  interval="10000"
  [keyboard]="true"
  [pauseOnHover]="true"
  [wrap]="true">
  <ng-template ngbSlide  *ngFor="let slide of sliderContent; let i = index" >
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <img style="filter: brightness(0.5);" src="{{slide.image}}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-content text-left">
      <div class="my-2"> 
        <h5><strong>{{slide.content.title}}</strong></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="my-2 text-wrap" style="width: 45rem">
        <h2 style="font-size: 4rem;"><strong>{{slide.content.heading}}</strong></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="my-2 text-wrap" style="width: 45rem">
        <p>{{slide.content.short_description}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="my-2 text-wrap">
       <a  [href]="slide.button.url"><button class="btn btn-secondary">{{slide.button.text}}</button></a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

and this is some css i have use to do some modifications:

```
.carousel-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 20;
  color: white;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  width : 20px!important;
  height: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  width : 20px!important;
  background-color: black;
  height: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width : 20px!important;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon{
  background-image: url('https://apufpel.com.br/assets/img/seta_prim.png');
}
.carousel-control-next-icon{
  background-image: url('https://apufpel.com.br/assets/img/seta_ult.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want show the carousel only when all the images are loaded, you can has in a variable

```
imagesLoaded:number=0
```

Then, your images can be like

```
<img style="filter: brightness(0.5);" [src]="slide.image" 
   (load)="imagesLoaded=imagesLoaded+1">
```

You can enclosed then your carousel in a div

```
<div [style.display]="imagesLoaded<sliderContent.length?'none':null>
   ..here your carousel..
</div>
```

See that you don't use `*ngIf` else display:none